# Adding server certificate validation to httplib.HTTPSConnection

Tags: python, validation, certificate, m2crypto, httplib

I've found that `httplib.HTTPSConnection` doesn't perform an automatic server certificate check. As far as I've understood the problem, I need to add that functionality manually, e.g. by subclassing this class as described [here](http://www.muchtooscrawled.com/2010/03/https-certificate-verification-in-python-with-urllib2/).

As I'm using Python2.4.5 and an upgrade is not possible under the given circumstances, I cannot use the workaround given in this blog post, because the `ssl` module has not been introduced until Py2.6.

I've been trying to avoid the usage of the `ssl` module by using `M2Crypto`. A promising approach for doing so is contained in [this blog post](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26/) (in the "Clients" section). But I haven't yet managed to override `httplib.HTTPSConnection.connect` appropriately by using that approach.

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 2):

Try this site maybe: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~danken/xmlrpc-ssl.html

It requires SSL but doesn't require the Python SSL module. It only requires Open SSL library.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close, but I still can't figure out how to implement the `connect` method from this.